# Cheap gravel bike

Tags: gravel

**Actual situation:** I ride my grandad's competition road bike (probably from early 80's) to commute and for fun. To give you an idea of my usual trip, my longest ride so far has been around 30 km.

**In the next months**, I'm moving to Stockholm and I'd like to buy a new bike with a budget from 200 to 500 EUR and there I think I'll travel only by bike (my estimation are about 20 km a day).
I really like to buy a road bike but I don't think it will be suitable for the winter and there is a lot of gravel paths I'd like to try. Therefore I thought of gravel bike.

I searched a lot for gravel bikes in my budget range but I have found only reviews about unknown brands sold by amazon, the only one sold by a physical shop, that I was able to find, is the decathlon's one and it is a bit over my budget. I've never bought a bike before then I prefer to by in a shop so I can try it.

**So my question is:**
Is it worth buying a gravel bike in that range? Or a mountain/road bike will be better for the money?

Feel free to ask for any other information and thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd suggest waiting until your move is complete, before buying more stuff.

Comment: You probably won’t get a new brand-name cyclocross or gravel bike for that price. They start at around 1000€. Road bikes start around 750€. I think the decathlons (Triban RC120, RC500) are the cheapest quality bikes and they might be able to fit 35mm studded tires for winter (certainly on the disc brake versions).

Comment: Yes, it is too little for a new one. My very cheap (still rides fine) gravel bike was around 800€ (Kellys Soot 30). Below that you have to get something second hand. Some stable cx bike with cantilever brakes could be really cheap. Very cheap supermarket bimes tend to be hardtail mountain bikes or hybrids instead.

Comment: I didn't think of buying a used one! Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At your budget, the best choice is to buy a used bike and learn to maintain it yourself. I would also recommend considering a cyclocross bike. These were the most common do-it-all drop bar bike until the gravel bike boom.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, did you know some good sites to learn how to maintain a bike?

Comment: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/ and https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help are good starting points